# apache, httpd.conf and symfony - can't see styles or images

Tags: apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4, httpd.conf

Well, seems that so far the tutorial is working as it suppose to.
However, I can't get it to use styles and images.

I am using win7 + wamp + symfony sandbox 1.4
The project i the Jobeet tutorial.
the path for the www folder is:

```
"d:\dev\wamp\www"
```

My project folder is located directly under the www path and named: 'banana'.
I changed the httpd.conf to be:

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "d:\dev\wamp\www\banana\web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "d:\dev\wamp\www\banana\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf "d:\dev\wamp\www\banana\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf"
  <Directory "d:\dev\wamp\www\banana\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now - I can access the 'frontend' files, but there are no styles as I wrote before.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I made a mistake.
The styles and stuff are configured only later in the tutorial.